# When i create some block in array, why the index 0 shouldn't be copy？

Tags: ios, objective-c, copy, automatic-ref-counting, block

```
    id getBlockArr() {
        NSInteger val = 10;
        return [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:^{ NSLog(@"value: %ld", val);},^{ NSLog(@"value: %ld", val);},^{ NSLog(@"value: %ld", val);}, nil];
    }

    int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            // insert code here...
            id arr = getBlockArr();
            void(^blk)(void) = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
            blk();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

From Apple's document, it will crash when the `blk` is released, but after I run this code, I see `*value: 10*` logged to the console. Then the application crashes. I set the breakpoint at the `arr`.

[image: a busy cat]
the block at index 0 is `NSMallocBlock`, it said it is copy to heap, but block at index 1 and index 2 is wrong, so what happen to this?

Comment: Ah, the mysteries of blocks. First, look at the crash in the debugger and see if you can figure out why the crashing is happening. Is this an ARC project, because you're not auto-releasing the NSArray if it is. Finally, assign each of the blocks to individual variables (`blk0`, `blk1`, `blk2`) then assemble the array from those and see with they are in `getBlockArray()`. Next, assign one block (`blk0`) and create the array with three references; `blk0,blk0,blk0,nil` It could just be compiler optimization, since the code for all three blocks is identical.

Comment: @JamesBucanek It is an ARC project, when i only insert one block into array, it runs correctly. it means only the block at index 0 will be copy, other is release, i don't know why

Comment: Given that all three blocks are in the array, all are going to be retained. However, in `main()` the first object gets put in an automatic, so is retained again, while the other two get released as soon as `arr` goes out of scope. Again, put these blocks in variables to examine them before building the array, then see if they're the same in `main`, then look at the stack when it crashes (and on what line it crashes) to figure out why. (Note that there's nothing obvious about this code that should make it crash.) The code is just unusual enough that it might even be a compiler bug...

Comment: If you declare the blocks as separate variables they all become NSMallocBlock, and there's no crash.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be connected with initWithObjects signature:

```
- (instancetype)initWithObjects:(ObjectType)firstObj, ...;
```

Only the first parameter is required, and the rest are optional. This hints at that it might be treated differently.

Normally if you declare block variables and capture a variable, they become `__ NSMallocBlock__`:

```
dispatch_block_t b1 = ^{ NSLog(@"value: %ld", val); };
dispatch_block_t b2 = ^{ NSLog(@"value: %ld", val); };
dispatch_block_t b3 = ^{ NSLog(@"value: %ld", val); };
```

If you don't declare a variable, but pass a block inside a function, it becomes a `__NSStackBlock__`:

```
void f(dispatch_block_t b) {
    b();
}
void g() {
    NSInteger val = 10;
    f(^{ NSLog(@"value1: %ld", val); });
}
```

The difference is similar to `@escaping` and not @escaping in Swift.

The `__NSStackBlock__` block is destroyed after the stack is destroyed, and access to it will crash when you try to access the memory after the function returns.

Note that the new syntax makes all 3 blocks to be `__NSMallocBlock__` and doesn't crash:

```
return @[
    ^{ NSLog(@"value1: %ld", val); },
    ^{ NSLog(@"value1: %ld", val); },
    ^{ NSLog(@"value1: %ld", val); }
];
```

My bet is that this quirk is caused by the way compiler treats all optional C (ellipsis) block parameters as `__NSStackBlock__` by default.

Interesting read: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Block-ABI-Apple.html

Answer (score 0):

The ARC specification actually doesn't guarantee that block literals that are passed directly to a function are copied. See the last sentence in the [Blocks section](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#blocks) of the ARC specification:

> With the exception of retains done as part of initializing a
>   `__strong` parameter variable or reading a `__weak` variable, whenever
>   these semantics call for retaining a value of block-pointer type, it
>   has the effect of a `Block_copy`. **The optimizer may remove such
>   copies when it sees that the result is used only as an argument to a
>   call.**

This kind of makes sense because when a function takes in a variable of block type, it is responsible for copying it if it needs to store that block past the end of that call. And if the function doesn't need to store that block past the end of the call (i.e. it will only use it synchronously), then there is no need to copy. So there is no need to always copy a block when passing to a function (which would defeat the whole optimization of putting blocks on the stack first to avoid excessive allocations).

However, there is a problem when you pass a block into a function parameter of regular object (not block) type (e.g. `id` or `NSObject *`). Blocks are Objective-C objects, so it's perfectly fine to pass them in this way. However, inside the called function, it just knows that the parameter is an object, and doesn't know that it's a block, so if it needs to store the object past the end of the call, it will just retain it, not copy it. If it's a stack block that wasn't copied, and it is used past the end of the scope that created it, bad things happen. To be extra-safe in this case, recent versions of the Objective-C compiler will apparently (even though it's not explicitly required by the ARC specification) always copy a value of block type that is passed to a function parameter of non-block type. That's what you see for the first argument in your case.

In this particular case, the parameters of the called function after the first are varargs (`...`). C varargs don't have types, so the compiler doesn't know what types the called function will decide to take out the arguments as. It could be that the function expects all varargs arguments to be blocks, of a certain block type. Or it could be that the function expects all varargs arguments to be of a regular object (non-block) type. It seems that whoever wrote the compiler feature that always copies blocks passed to non-block type parameters, didn't decide to always copy it when passed to varargs. So that's why the blocks after the first were not copied.

I think it's good practice to always explicitly copy a block that is passed to a function as non-block type parameter where the function will store the argument beyond the call.